# python RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration - popping out randomly during scipy import

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, import, scipy

I'm playing with torch and kalman filter, and I'm importing it in a bit of a non-standard way with `importlib`, more or less like this:

```
import importlib


class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def tst(self):
        torch = importlib.import_module("torch")
        kalman = importlib.import_module("filterpy.kalman")


foo = Foo()
foo.tst()
```

My program is not spawning any thread (at least I'm not spawning any thread myself and I checked the output of `threading.enumerate()` which contains only `MainThread`)

I'm facing a following problem:

Every now and again (approximately in 10% of tries) I'm observing `RuntimeError` thrown by `scipy` during that import:

```
  File "/opt/my_package/imp.py", line 492, in import_class
    imported_module = importlib.import_module("filterpy.kalman")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filterpy/kalman/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .EKF import *
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filterpy/kalman/EKF.py", line 28, in <module>
    from filterpy.stats import logpdf
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filterpy/stats/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filterpy/stats/stats.py", line 32, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import norm, multivariate_normal
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 391, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import _discrete_distns
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py", line 1266, in <module>
    pairs = list(globals().items())
```

Funny bit is that I get this error when running my dockerized code in one machine (AWS G4 instance), while not seeing it on another machine with same docker image. I see that on the machine where this issue happens it is much more probable to experience it if I invoke it straight after boot, the longer the machine is booted the less likely issue will manifest.

I found this closed ticket in scipy repository: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11479 - but the problem does not seem to be recognized (at least I can't see the proper explanation of issue).

There was another question asked on SO here, but it did not get any answer apart from useful comment about calls to `list()`: [Bug in Python 3.5? list(globals().items()) caused RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903472/bug-in-python-3-5-listglobals-items-caused-runtimeerror-dictionary-chang)

There was also this question on SO: [Python: globals().items() iterations try to change a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532675/python-globals-items-iterations-try-to-change-a-dict) - however scipy does not iterate over `globals().items()` in a loop, they use list comprehensions. Also the problem is not easily reproducible - it does not manifest each time, from my observation it manifests randomly. Based on this question adding `pairs = []` before calling `pairs = list(globals().items())` would solve the problem, even though if that was the case then we should see this issue on each run.

I do understand that `list(globals().items())` could be the case if my program was a multi-threaded program. But I only have `MainThread`, how is it possible that `globals().items()` changes while iterating over it?

Even though I'm running single-threaded code I tried to wrap my code like this (as suggested here: [Forcing a thread to block all other threads from executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317120/forcing-a-thread-to-block-all-other-threads-from-executing#answer-29324345)) but without luck:

```
original_interval = sys.getswitchinterval()
sys.setswitchinterval(1000)
# imports
sys.setswitchinterval(original_interval)
```

I also looked at disassembly of `pairs = list(globals().items())` but since I have no experience in reading disassembly code I can't see any issue:

```
import dis
dis.dis("pairs = list(globals().items())")

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (globals)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
              8 CALL_METHOD              0
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (pairs)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'm running on python 3.8.0 within `nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04` container. Scipy version: `1.6.3`. I'm not sure if this has anything to do but I also have `numpy 1.20.3` and `torch 1.7.1+cu110`

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to post - it's `1.6.3`

Comment: We had a similar problem for continuous distributions in the past, we may be able to use a similar fix for this. Do you have a MWE that we could use to test this issue?

Comment: I'm still investigating the root cause of this, and it's not helping that I cannot reproduce it each time, it happens randomly. Looks like scipy team already provided a fix in their repository, though I'd love to understand why is this happening.

Comment: @Greg0ry What happens if you import this module the "normal" way? I.e. just `import filterpy.kalman`; do you still observe this behavior? Also, did you report this problem to https://bugs.python.org/? Even if it's not a bug, there might be useful advice on why exactly this is happening. Actually I thought `list(d.items())` to be thread-safe since thread switching can only happen between bytecodes (?).

Comment: Thanks @a_guest, I can't reproduce if I go for `import ...` option, however the system I'm working on requires me to use `importlib`.. I am trying to refine minimal working example where issue would be reproducible reliably outside of AWS G4 instance but it proves to be challenging. I also had same thoughts on `list(d.items())` but on another hand this is a single-threaded program and I am definitely not an expert when it comes to inner workings of cpython interpreter...